# Cython compiled C extension: ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function

Tags: python, cython, python-extensions

I have just compiled part of my C library as an extension using Cython, as a "proof of concept". I managed to hack the code (const correctnes problems etc aside), to finally get an extension built.

However, when I attempted to import the newly created extension, I got the following error:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

I am using Cythn 0.11.2 and Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 10.0.4

Comment: What command line did you use for generate the .c ? How did you compile it ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I've found that a frequent cause of this problem is, when using a distutils setup file to compile the code, that the .pyx base name does not match the extension name, e.g:

```
ext = Extension(name='different', sources=['cython_ext.pyx']) # Won't work
```

To avoid the problem the extension name should be exactly the same, in this case, `cython_ext`.

Comment: Nice call. Does anyone know why this works, and why a different name does not?

Comment: @Dologan, thanks, it helped!
I want to make your answer more complete: the `name` can be nested like `make.something.useful.cython_ext`. The point is that the module name (word after the last point) should be the same as the name of the source file.
I guess, it would be helpful to put such positive example in your answer.

Comment: thank you thank you. Amazing that this many years later there still isn't a *&# error message that explains this.

Answer (score 36):

It appears that it's a bug/feature in Cython.  I had the same thing, but simply added:

```
STUFF = "Hi"
```

to the top of my .pyx file and the issue went away.  It appears if there is no global initialization (a **cinit** or setting a global variable), that the required initialization code isn't generated.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe that actually worked, but it fixed the same bug in my library.

Comment: Worked for me as well

Answer (score 2):

This is a very late answer - but I just had the same error, and mine went away when I used `__cinit__` instead of `__init__`. I'm still learing about extension types so currently I do not know why this happens. :) (You can take a look at http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/extension_types.html#initialization-cinit-and-init) Hope this is useful to someone.

Comment: This is a _very_ late comment, but I think this answer would relate to a `cdef class` rather than a module, so probably not the problem reported. However, I realise it's probably difficult to know what issue you were fixing at this stage...

Answer (score 1):

Another really late answer in my case I had accidentally called cython in a terminal that was running python2, while trying to use the generated library from a terminal that was on another python environment, using python3.

Using the same python version everywhere fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Likewise a late answer... but I kept finding my way back to this question in particular.  It probably is related to the mismatched names issue that Dologan addresses.

What happened in my case was that I was adapting an example I'd gotten to work, and got the `module does not define init function` error.  This was verified by using (e.g.)

> nm -m build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/myproj.so

In this command's output I searched for 'init' and found

> 000000000000c0d0 (__TEXT,__text) external _initexample

I had removed all instances of 'example' from my `setup.py` and .pyx file, but this persisted even after removing the extension from `site-packages`, removing the build and dist folders, etc. I finally found that the .cpp file being generated from my .pyx file was still referring to the class name in the example.  Once I reran my `setup.py`, import works, and indeed the .so file includes

> 000000000000c0a0 (__TEXT,__text) external _initmyproj

Answer (score 0):

I've also ran into this problem. Make sure that your Cython file contains at least one of the following:

- a normal Python `def`
- a normal Python class (not `cdef class`)
- a line of Python initialization, eg. `a=None` or a logger load

Otherwise Cython won't generate a `PyInit` routine needed to load the module, and as such the module won't be importable by Python.

Comment: I can't get it to fail even with an empty pyx file. If you have an example of something that doesn't work it'd probably be useful to report it as a bug as https://github.com/cython/cython/issues.

Answer (score -1):

This is solved by adding a doc-string to your functions.

Comment: There is no reason that should help. Can you explain?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and was solved by running the main .py script in "Execute in a dedicated console " mode.  Available in Tools - Preferences - Run.

Answer (score -1):

I solve it by

```
def cinit(self): pass
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This sounds like you had a problem with a `cdef class` while this question is about modules. I'd be surprised if this was correct. Also note `__cinit__` not `cinit` - the double underscores are used for special methods in Python.