symbol not found in flat namespace '_GOMP_loop_end_nowait' when importing Python wrapper made with Cython (MacOS)
I'm working on a C++ code that makes use of openmp on MacOS. The code normally gets compiled with a makefile, and the resulting binary accepts some arguments in input and outputs arrays as files. However I need to run this code many thousands of times in quick succession and use the results in Python, so saving and reading files from the disk slows everything down considerably. For this reason I decided to write a python wrapper to access the output directly from memory.
I did some research, and Cython seemed the best option for the task, so I went to work and produced 5 files:

a C++ header defining a class that collects the input arguments and the main function that was previously being compiled with the makefile as method of the class;
a .cpp file containing the actual functions;
a .pxd file for the definitions in Cython;
a .pyx file wrapping the class from point 1;
a setup.py to compile everything.

When I execute python setup.py build_ext --inplace, I get the following output:
running build_ext
building 'pyGridSPT' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
g++-13 -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/Users/matteo/Documents/work/VENV_pybird/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c gridSPT_lib_wrapper.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/gridSPT_lib_wrapper.o -fopenmp -lgsl -lgslcblas -lfftw3f_omp -lfftw3f
g++-13: warning: this compiler does not support x86 ('-arch' option ignored)
In file included from gridSPT_lib.cpp:13,
                 from gridSPT_lib_wrapper.cpp:1237:
fielddata_v2.hpp: In instantiation of 'void FieldData<T>::apply_filter_standard(int) [with T = float]':
gridSPT_lib.cpp:138:39:   required from here
fielddata_v2.hpp:632:21: warning: unused variable 'ntasks' [-Wunused-variable]
  632 |                 int ntasks = omp_get_num_threads();
      |                     ^~~~~~
fielddata_v2.hpp: In instantiation of 'void FieldData<T>::apply_filter_standard_iso(int) [with T = float]':
gridSPT_lib.cpp:140:43:   required from here
fielddata_v2.hpp:683:21: warning: unused variable 'ntasks' [-Wunused-variable]
  683 |                 int ntasks = omp_get_num_threads();
      |                     ^~~~~~
fielddata_v2.hpp: In instantiation of 'void FieldData<T>::apply_filter_23() [with T = float]':
gridSPT_lib.cpp:142:33:   required from here
fielddata_v2.hpp:531:21: warning: unused variable 'ntasks' [-Wunused-variable]
  531 |                 int ntasks = omp_get_num_threads();
      |                     ^~~~~~
fielddata_v2.hpp: In instantiation of 'void FieldData<T>::apply_filter_23_iso() [with T = float]':
gridSPT_lib.cpp:144:37:   required from here
fielddata_v2.hpp:582:21: warning: unused variable 'ntasks' [-Wunused-variable]
  582 |                 int ntasks = omp_get_num_threads();
      |                     ^~~~~~
fielddata_v2.hpp: In instantiation of 'FieldData<T> operator*(T, const FieldData<T>&) [with T = float]':
gridSPT_lib.cpp:161:32:   required from here
fielddata_v2.hpp:370:17: warning: unused variable 'ng' [-Wunused-variable]
  370 |   long long int ng = b.get_size();
      |                 ^~
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
g++-13 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/gridSPT_lib_wrapper.o -L/opt/homebrew/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyGridSPT.cpython-311-darwin.so
g++-13: warning: this compiler does not support x86 ('-arch' option ignored)
copying build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/pyGridSPT.cpython-311-darwin.so ->

As you can see I have a bunch of warnings for unused variables (I believe the variable "ntasks" is especially relevant), but the code compiles without issues. In the Python interpreter, I then try to import the wrapper's class with from pyGridSPT import pyGridSPTField, however I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/matteo/Documents/work/repo/GridSPT/GridBSPT_RSD/second_order/python/pyGridSPT.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_GOMP_loop_end_nowait'

I've searched online, but I couldn't find anything of use. This seems to be problem only on MacOS, but in all cases it seems to be a problem tied to the use of the native Apple's clang (which I'm already avoiding, I use g++ installed with brew).
From the exception I think the problem must be with how openmp is being handled during compilation, however I don't really have experience with compiling things beside specifying library paths, so I'm not sure how to even debug this. I might have made some mistake in my C++ class as well, since I'm new to C/C++.
For reference, this is how the makefile looks like (compiles without issues, binary works flawlessly):
#------------------------------------------------------

TARGET1 = gridSPT_RSD.exe

#------------------------------------------------------
# Default Parameters
#------------------------------------------------------

#CC  = icpc -std=c++11
#CC  = icpc
#OPT = -O3 -I/usr/local/include -fopenmp
#INC1 = fielddata_v2.hpp vectorfield_v2.hpp util.hpp
#LIB = -fopenmp -lgsl -lgslcblas -lsrfftw_threads -lsfftw_threads -lsrfftw -lsfftw -L/usr/local/lib

CC       = g++-13
GSL_DIR  = /opt/homebrew/
FFTW_DIR = /opt/homebrew/

OPT = -O3 -g -I${GSL_DIR}/include -I${FFTW_DIR}/include -fopenmp
INC = fielddata_v2_fftw3.hpp vectorfield_v2.hpp util.hpp
LIB = -fopenmp -L${GSL_DIR}/lib -L${FFTW_DIR}/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lfftw3f_omp -lfftw3f

#---
# Source Files
#---

OBJ1 = main_PT_RSD.o

#------------------------------------------------------
# rules
#------------------------------------------------------

gridPT : $(TARGET1)

$(TARGET1): $(OBJ1)
    $(CC) $(OPT) -o $(TARGET1) $(OBJ1) $(LIB)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) -c $< $(OPT)

$(OBJ1): $(INC1)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET1)
    rm -f $(OBJ1)
    rm -f *~
#-----------------------------------------------------

And this is how I wrote my setup.py:
# compile with: python setup.py build_ext --inplace
# remove build folder before recompiling

import os
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils import sysconfig

# MacOS (specify compiler installed with brew) 
os.environ["CC"] = "g++-13"
sysconfig.get_config_vars()["CC"] = "g++-13"
sysconfig.get_config_vars()["CXX"] = "g++-13"
sysconfig.get_config_vars()["MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"] = "11"

# external libaries
extension = Extension(
    "pyGridSPT",
    sources=["gridSPT_lib_wrapper.pyx"],
    include_dirs=["/opt/homebrew/include"],
    library_dirs=["/opt/homebrew/lib"],
    language="c++",
    extra_compile_args=[
        "-fopenmp",
        "-lgsl",
        "-lgslcblas",
        "-lfftw3f_omp", 
        "-lfftw3f"
    ]
)

setup(ext_modules=cythonize([extension]))

Let me know if I should provide more details.
What I tried:

created the files required for the Cython-based wrapper;
tried to mirror the makefile of the C++ code in the setup.py.

What I expected to happen:

the wrapper compiles successfully;
the wrapper can be imported in Python without issues.

What actually happened:

the wrapper compiled successfully (with warnings);
the wrapper cannot be imported in Python due to missing symbols (likely something related to openmp).


I would say that the important and missing part is the C++ source that you compile (and how you compile it). There is many things in your setup that can go wrong, like: bad flags in copy-pasted Makefile, incorrectly written python wrapper, some issue in setup.py. Try to simplify your problem: write simple foo.cpp with simple void foo() that uses openmp loop, then write a pybind11 wrapper around it, build it with cmake and see if that works.

I suspect you need to pass -fopenmp as a link argument as well as a compile argument

@DavidW That was exactly the problem, or at least part of it. I managed to make it work after changing to the following: Extension(..., extra_compile_args=[-fopenmp], extra_link_args=["-fopenmp", "-lgsl", "-lgslcblas", "-lfftw3f_omp", "-lfftw3f"]. It didn't work immediately after that, I got an unrelated error at import time because Cython was not parsing my class definition in the .pyx file. Resolved that one using this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/13976504/24905459 . Now everything works as expected though, thanks!
